# Define with scope inside

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to jump over some scope to access directly to a static variable without write all of my scope.

`nts::CLI::Mode::AMode::Out`

where Out is pointer to static variable to the one I would like to access by writing

`nts::Out`

is there a way to do this using prepocessor define or another pointer in my namespace nts ?

Maybe is just an architecture error, should I put my static var in nts namespace ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? What is the motivation here ? If you want to reduce the amount of writing, you could just say `using nts::CLI::Mode::Amode::Out` and use `Out` happily in your code without having to write full namespace qualified name again and again

Comment: Are `nts`, `CLI`, `Mode` and `AMode` all namespaces?

Comment: No, nts is a namespace, others are class

Comment: I just moved my Out into nts namespace, this resolved my problem and this is more consistent

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way is to define an alias, for example, for your specific case:
`using Out = CLI::Mode::AMode::Out;` inside the `nts` namespace.

Of course you could define any other name alias, in any level of namespace or class, like `using O = nts::CLI::Mode::AMode::Out;`, and `O` is the new name, etc.

Including the whole namespace is generally frowned upon, because if the resulting ‘namespace pollution’, but works too: `using nts::CLI::Mode::AMode;`.